# How to get all of the exceptions of Python3 C API?

Tags: c++, python-3.6, python-c-api

I have a script named `main_test.py`, which has a syntax_error, is what I want to catch and show. 
`f = open(path, "r+"# )`
And I try to import this in C++, code looks like below, already set path: 
`PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("main_test");`

I use `PyErr_Print()` and `PyErr_PrintEx(1)` to catch scripts errors.

Everything works fine in my centOS server with python3.6. But it does not work in my ubuntu docker, I cannot get anything from stderr to show.

What should I do?

Comment: What does “anything from stderr” mean?  Can you write to stderr *yourself*?